# How can I put log tickmarks on a secondary axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am doing a plot with a secondary y axis which is just a multiplicative scaling of the primary axis to display it in alternative units.

My primary y axis is log scaled, with log tickmarks from `annotation_logticks`. Is there any way to get log tickmarks in the secondary y axis in the scaled units? Currently they're in the primary units.

```r
library(tidyverse)

x=c(100,1000000,100,1000000)
y=c(0.01,0.01,0.32,0.32)
z=c(1,1,0.5,0.5)
data <- data.frame(x,y,z)

data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, z = z, fill = z)) +
  geom_raster(interpolate=TRUE) + 
  coord_fixed(ratio = 1, xlim = c(100,1000000), ylim=c(0.01,0.32)) +
  annotation_logticks(sides = "trbl") + 
  scale_x_log10() +
  scale_y_log10(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . / 0.0714,
                                    breaks=c(0.2,0.5,1,2,5),
                                    name = "Sec. Axis")) + 
  scale_fill_continuous() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-08-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

extra pics:

Currently, the right axis looks like:
[image: wrong right axis log tickmarks]

I would like the axis to look like:
[image: correct right axis log tickmarks]

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean. The secondary axis is in units that are about 15 times greater than those on the primary axis. They are not the same. Could you expand on your expected output please?

Comment: The secondary axis is also log scaled, but the log tick marks from annotation_logticks on the right axis are aligned with the primary axis on the left. I want logticks on the right axis aligned with the scale on the right axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to do this directly with `annotation_logticks`, since the only positional parameter you can change is `base`. However, changing the base does not affect the position of the main breakpoint, which is determined by the primary axis values.

However, you can achieve a similar effect by manually setting the breaks and labels on the secondary axis:

```r
data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, z = z, fill = z)) +
  geom_raster(interpolate=TRUE) + 
  coord_fixed(ratio = 1, xlim = c(100,1000000), ylim=c(0.01,0.32)) +
  annotation_logticks(sides = "tbl") + 
  scale_x_log10() +
  scale_y_log10(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . * 14,
                                    breaks= c(seq(0.1, 1, 0.1), 2:5),
                                    labels =  replace(character(14), 
                                                      c(2, 5, 10, 11, 14), 
                                                      c(0.2, 0.5, 1, 2, 5)),
                                    name = "Sec. Axis")) + 
  scale_fill_continuous() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Allan. This was the only way we could find to do it. In the end I went the photoshop route, and copied the left axis markings over the right.